# How to create half overlapped Image to a cardview in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I want to make something like this in the android studio can anyone help me?

[image]

How to place that image left to that card view?

Comment: you wants to make the layout like the above mention image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all, break down your layout structure and understand the layers.

A Parent layout with `horizontal` gravity(ie: LinearLayout) or a relative layout.

And as child views-

```
A Fixed size moon(ie: 100dp).

A Card view with layoutMarginStart="-50dp"(half the moon).
```

Logically, That should work.

--If the moon goes under the card use elevation more than the card.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this out it will work same as you want just replace your UI accordingly 


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/quantum_pink"
            app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="abcdefghijk"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:translationZ="2dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                
            </LinearLayout>
    
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:translationZ="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: yeah, it is working perfectly fine but one thing that I couldn't understand what is _20sdp refers to.

Comment: Well i use implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6' for support different screen size. 


You can replace _20sdp with simple 20 dp also

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConstraintLayout with guidelines or negative margin to achieve this XML view.

Comment: Its better to provide answer with some code example. Suggesting stuff qualifies as a comment only.